# TI manual naming conventions?

Tags: datasheet, documentation

Can anyone shed some light on the naming conventions used by Texas Instruments manuals/guides/documents. For example slaa490, slau337. Is there a pattern hidden? Anyway to tell, just by looking at the name of the file, what product family it refers to?

Comment: Care to reconsider your "accept" vote? In the meantime, you got a perfect answer from a TI guy ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no rhyme or reason to their naming conventions.  Keep in mind that the TI of today is the result of at least 7 acquisitions in the last 15 years, and probably several dozen over the whole lifetime of the company.  Each time they buy a new company they inherit their naming conventions.

You might see some resemblance of reason within a small product line (their audio ADC/DAC's, for example), but that will not extend to their other product lines.

Comment: "Each time they buy a new company they inherit their naming conventions." True for part numbers, but not for literature numbers, which is the question here. Those all get a TI number when a merger/acquisition takes place. NSC's AN-263 still has its headline ("AN-263"), but the filename/document number is now SNOA665C; http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=snoa665c&fileType=pdf.

Comment: -1 This is totally wrong.

Answer (score 9):

TI employee here. I went and dug up the naming scheme for literature numbers. It's pretty long, and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post the whole thing here, but I can give an overview and some examples. Credit to Zebonaut for getting a lot right without the benefit of insider info. :-)

The first three letters are the product classification. This normally indicates the product family, but is also used for translated documents. For example:

```
AME    Latin America
CZH    Czech
GER    German
JAJ    Japanese
RUS    Russian
ZHC    Chinese
```

Most of the remaining product classifications start with S, which I assume stands for "semiconductor". A notable exception is the DLP series of micromirror-based MEMS display devices:

```
DLP    Digital Light Processing
```

Educational Technology (the calculator group) doesn't have a classification. Their manuals don't seem to have lit numbers.

Within the semiconductor family, it looks like a mix of product types and acquired companies. The major groups are:

```
SBx    Burr-Brown
SCx    Mostly CMOS with what looks like early digital products
SDx    Standard logic and digital interfacing
SGx    Military
SLx    Linear and mixed-signal
SNx    National Semiconductor
SOx    Optoelectronics
SPx    Processors
SSx    Marketing, university, and lobbying documents
SWx    Wireless
```

The third letter gives the product type. For example, here's what's listed under SLx:

```
SLA    Data Acquisition, Data Converters, Multimedia, Video
SLB    Optoelectronics (TSL)
SLC    Linear Comparators
SLD    Display Drivers, Power ICs, Peripheral Drivers
SLE    MSDS Emerging Markets
SLF    Special Functions (TLS)
SLI    Intelligent Power and Power ICs
SLL    Line Circuits, Data Transmission (ALS/LBC/Interface), 1394
SLM    Mixed Signal Processor (TSS)
SLN    LinCMOS Products
SLO    Op Amps
SLP    Power (Transistors)
SLR    Peripheral Drivers
SLS    Sonar
SLT    Timers, Power Trends
SLU    Acquired Unitrode, Benchmarq Products
SLV    Voltage Regulators
SLW    Telecom
SLX    LinASICs
SLY    Mixed Signal and Analog Family
SLZ    Thin Shrink Small Outline (TSSOP) Packages
```

The fourth letter gives the document type. There's a lot of reuse here. I've listed the most popular types below. The formatting is weird because I copied it directly from the list.

```
xxxA    Application Notes,Chapter Extracts, Release Notes, Design Manuals, Designer's Handbooks, Primers, Design Considerations, Technical White Papers, System Block Diagrams,Contributed Articles
xxxC    Catalogs, Master Selection Guides, CD-ROM's, Diskettes, Software: TI device software, Software Support Packages & Modules, Logic equation files to program TI hardware devices, Other: Image, screensaver, wallpaper, Software: CODEC
xxxM    Mini-Brochures, Slim Jims, IBIS Model, BSDL Model, Macromodels, TINA-TI Reference Designs, TINA-TI Spice Model, PSpice Model, HSpice Model, VerilogA Model, TISpice Model, VHDL Model, S-Parameter Model, Power Model, IBIS-SMI Model
xxxS    Data Sheets, Data Manuals on Single Products, MacroLibraries
xxxT    Direct Mail Materials, Product Bulletin, Technical Brief, Marketing Selection Guide
xxxU    Owners Manuals, Software Manuals, User's Guides, Reference Guides, Availability Guides, Getting Started, Installation, Technical Reference, Demo Board
xxxZ    Important Notice, Field Sales Office(FSO) Listing, OOPS Card, Manual Update Sheet,Inserts (Adam's note: This type includes errata sheets)
```

Short version: A for app notes, C for software, M for models, S for datasheets, T for promotional material, U for user's guides, and Z for errata.

After the first four letters there are three characters that identify the unique document. This can be either a number or a mix of letters and numbers. The last character is always a number. Letters are used when the classification/type runs out of three-digit numbers. As best I can tell, the numbers are assigned chronologically based on when the document is added to the system.

The last character is a letter that indicates the revision. It's blank for the first release. The next release is A, then B, and so forth. I found a couple documents in the database that had wrapped around to AA, but that's extremely rare.

Here's an example. The technical reference manual for one of our recent C2000 MCUs currently has literature number [SPRUHM8E](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=spruhm8). This breaks down as follows:

```
SPR         Digital signal processors
   U        User's guide
    HM8     Document number
       E    Fifth revision after release
```

SLAA490 (Capacitive Touch Software Library Programmer's Guide) is:

```
SLA         Data acquisition, converters, multimedia, video
   A        Application note or manual that's not for an IC
    490     Document number (assigned in 2011 according to the database)
       _    Initial release
```

SLAU337 (430BOOST-SENSE1 - Capacitive Touch
BoosterPack for the LaunchPad User's Guide) is:

```
SLA         Data acquisition, converters, multimedia, video
   U        User's guide
    337     Document number (assigned in 2011 according to the database)
       _    Initial release
```

This system seems to have been around since at least the early 1990s, so there's some pretty old stuff in there. I found lit numbers for envelopes, paper newsletters, floppy disks... A lot of the categories probably aren't even used anymore. It's pretty complex, but that's what happens when a big company spends decades churning out documents.

Comment: Nice! I was always curious about this. :) Seems to make sense -- SNVS725G, Semiconductor, National Semiconductor acquiried...V is probably power, datasheet, unique number, Rev. G. I like decoder rings.

Comment: Yep! SNV is National Semiconductor power products.

Comment: Cool. And I thought I would have to go loitering at the suburban trains' station in Freising, close to our local TI plant, around _Feierabend_ (5:30 pm), and bribe your fellow workers into turning on their notebook computers and log into the TI network...

Answer (score 6):

```
OLDSTUFF (as in: Guess I was not really right...)
```

Well, I just found something that makes me think there *is* a rhyme or reason:

[This data sheet](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4011a.pdf), acquired from **H**arris **S**emiconductor, features the letters **H** and **S** at spots 3 and 4: SC**HS**313. This *could* mean something, *maybe*.

For one, Harris was acquired quite a while ago (1998), and for newer acquisitions, there may be another rhyme... And secondly, I might actually be just quite wrong here, after having reconsidered this all-too-easy combination of letters.

```
/OLDSTUFF
```

As it stands today, my best guess is that a **B** as the second letter might be a reference to a part/document acquired from Burr Brown ([2000-08-24](http://www.ti.com/sc/bb2)), just like **N** as the second letter might indicate "National Semiconductor" (acquired [2011-09-23](http://www.ti.com/corp/docs/investor_relations/acquisitions_divestitures.html)). It appers that many of TI's own parts have literature designators with **D** for digital/standard logic and **L** for linear/analog parts.

The third letter might be about the general type of part - like **O**perational Amplifier or **A**nalog-to-Digital Converter (including everything that can be considered "mixed signal") or **P** for power transistors (they have stopped making the famous TIP* power transistors a long time ago), **U** for power ICs (probably makes sense if we remember that TI's power IC portfolio really took off when they acquired **U**nitrode on October 15, 1999, but may be arbitrary because P was already used for discrete power transistors?).

The fourth letter might indicate whether it's a Data **S**heet or an **A**pplication note or a **U**ser's guide.

Examples:

[OPA627/SBOS165A](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=OPA627&fileType=pdf); [DAC902/SBAS094B](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=DAC902&fileType=pdf); [OPA622 Application Note/SBOA073](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=sboa073&fileType=pdf)(all ex Burr Brown) 
[LM107/SNOSBS4A](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=LM107-N&fileType=pdf); [ADC121S705/SNAS355B](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=ADC121S705&fileType=pdf); [AN-263, Sine Wave Generation Techniques, Application Note/SNOA665C](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=snoa665c&fileType=pdf) (all ex National Semiconductor)
[TIP31*/SLPS067](http://www.ee.nmt.edu/~wedeward/EE321L/FA08/tip31.pdf) (discontinued by TI)

Then, there is the obvious: If there is a letter at the end, it's the document's revision, as in [the TL431 datasheet](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf), which currently (June 2016) is at revision <s>L</s> O.

```
xxxxnnnr
||||\|/|
|||| | +--- Revision (A, B, C, ...)
|||| |
|||| +----- Number (assigned chronologically)
||||
|||+------- Document type
|||         -S: Data Sheet
|||         -A: Application Note
|||         -U: User's Guide
|||
||+-------- What type of part is the document about?
||          -O: Operational Amplifier
||          -A: Mixed Signal (ADC, DAC, ...)
||          -P: Power Discrete (Transistor, ...)
||          -U: Power Management IC
||          -H: Standard Logic, formerly Harris (?)
||
|+--------- General family of the part
|           -D: Standard logic, native TI
|           -L: other than standard logic, native TI
|           -B: acquired from Burr Brown
|           -C: acquired from Harris Semiconductor
|           -N: acquired from National Semiconductor
|
+---------- Always the same
            -S: no idea why it's always (?) S...
```

Maybe if we keep our eyes open, we will find more rhymes and reasons.

---

Ok, let's try your examples...

**slaa490**
xLxx - literature about a part that's something else than just standard logic, developed by TI 
xxAx - something "mixed signal" (kind of redundant with the info already buried in L)
xxxA - an application note

So, what do we have? "*Capacitive Touch Software Library, Programmer's Guide, related to MSP430 microcontrollers...*"

**slau337**
xxxU - as above, but a User's Guide for an Evaluation Board.

Let's check... "*430BOOST-SENSE1 - Capacitive Touch BoosterPack for the LaunchPad, User's Guide*"

Hmmm... I guess that was slightly better than a complete failure, probably?

Answer (score 1):

Naming conventions on chips can be very inconvenient. National has some data converter sets that are logic: like the ADC121S021 is a 1x 12-bit 200ksps A/D where the ADC102S051 is a 2x 10-bit 500ksps ADC. But you still need to know which digit stands for 12-bit, and what '021' is.

TI has many brands merged into their productline.You may see some burr brown products between their normal instrumentation amplifiers. Also TPS and TLV seem to be used a lot for power products, but TLV is also used on some opamps.

Just type the 'generic' name (prefix + number) in google , and you usually will see what it is.

Comment: He's asking about *manuals*, not *chips*, however...